# Abbreviate states in Geocomplete

Tags: geocomplete

Is there a way to abbreviate the states in geocomplete?

I am currently using the data-geocode administrative_area_level_1 to show the sate but need it to be abbreviated - not the full name.

Answer (score 0):

You just add short to short to the end of the administrative_area_level_1 as follows:

```
    <label>State</label>
    <input name="administrative_area_level_1_short" type="text" value="">


I tried it for Colorado and it gave CO. I think this is what you wanted. All the best.
```